# custom 'use strict' like directives

Tags: javascript, use-strict

I'm looking for a better logging/debugging method for my project. So I came up with the idea to use custom directives like the 'use strict'.

Is it possible to write something like this

```
function xyz () {
   'loglevel: info';
   /// Some other code
   logging.debug("foobar");
}
```

And if xyz has a directive loglevel >= info the logging.debug will not log a message.

Is this possible?

Comment: It might be possible with some convoluted hacks, but a *much* simpler solution would be just `logging.level = 'info';`.

Comment: It's not possible unless you write a custom pre-processor that parses the file and replaces the logging statements for you.

Comment: I think you are looking for "decorators".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you cannot create directives like that without some real hackery in converting the current function to a string and and checking for the directive. it would not be worth the time to check. You can however use functional decorators to perform the same function, it's a little tricky to get your head around, but is very powerful once you do.

I should mention that es7 will have easier decorators to implement. They are still created the same way. They are a function that returns a function in place of the original function. but they have sugar eg.

> sorry I couldn't stop so went a bit far. but now it's a pretty complete example.

```
@logLevel('warn')
function xyz(){
  // do some stuff
}
```

or

```
@logLevelInfo
function abc(){
  // do some stuff
}
```

```js
// if this is false the logging will not occur
var __debug__ = true;
var __debug_levels__ = ['error', 'warn'];

// decorator to create a log level function. this is a function
// that takes the log type, that returns a function that takes the
// function you want to decorate with the logging functionality 
// that returns the decorated function that you call as xyz( ...arguments ).
function logLevel( type ) {
  return function logger(fn) {
    return function() {
      // save time if __debug__ is false
      if( __debug__ ){
        // run the decorated function and get the result
        // may as well wrap it in a try catch in case there are any errors
        try {
          var result = fn.apply(this, arguments);
        } catch( e ){
          console.error( e );
        }
        if( __debug_levels__.indexOf( type ) > -1 ){
          // log the result to the console or whatever functionality you require
          console[ type || 'log' ](result);
        }
        // return the result so you can do something with the result
        return result;
      }
      return fn.apply(this, arguments);
    }
  }
}

// this will return the first function that takes the function to decorate
var logLevelInfo = logLevel('warn');
var logLevelDebug = logLevel('error');


// here we are using the decorators to wrap the original function
var xyz = logLevelInfo(function xyz( arg ) {
  return arg + 'bar';
});

// same here but we are using the other decorator
var abc = logLevelDebug(function abc( arg ){
  return arg + 'baz';
});

// these functions have been decorated to perform the logging
// functionality on the returned result
xyz('foo'); //=> 'foobar'
abc('foo'); //=> 'foobaz'
```

```html
<script src="http://codepen.io/synthet1c/pen/WrQapG.js"></script>
```

Comment: Worth mentioning that decorators are available in Babel with the appropriate presets.

Answer (score -2):

```
function Log(level)
{
    var levels = { 'debug': 10, 'info': 20};

    function write(lvl)
    {
        var handle = function(msg)
        {
            if (levels[lvl] <= levels[level]) 
                console.log(lvl + ': ' + msg);
        };

        return handle;
    }

    for (var i in levels)
    {
        this[i] = write(i);
    }
}

var log1 = new Log('info');
log1.info('hello'); // will result with an output
log1.debug('hello'); // still has an output output

var log2 = new Log('debug');
log2.info('hello'); // no output here
```